# Filtering date fields in Views - How can I test for NULL

Tags: views, datetime

When I add a date field to the filter criteria, I get a choice of operators "Is less than", "Is less than or equal to" etc, but no way to test is or is not NULL.

How do I test for these conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must not have scrolled down far enough. For future reference, if you add a Filter Criterion to a View, and the field in question is a Date, the **Operator** selector allows you the options `Is not empty (NOT NULL)` and `Is empty (NULL)`. But you have to scroll right down the list to find them.

Note this is in Drupal 7 with **Views 3.13**, **Date Views** and **Date API** modules enabled.

Answer (score 1):

For User "Last access" or "Last login" dates the "Is empty (NULL)" option is not available.

For those particular dates, an alternative is to test for "Greater than 1970-01-02".